# how to try SourceMaps with GWT?

Tags: gwt, google-chrome

https://plus.google.com/u/1/110412141990454266397/posts/Nvr6Se6eAPh

does anyone know how to try it with last build of GWT (from svn) and Chrome Canary?

Answer (score 4):

See http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/SourceMaps

it's only a matter of adding the following to your `gwt.xml`:

```
<set-property name="compiler.useSourceMaps" value="true" />
```

The compiler will then output source maps and the necessary *triggers* in the JS code (currently only for the `safari` permutation, to target Chrome only).

Beware, it's rather resource consuming! Be prepared to bump your `-Xmx` et al.